# Download attachment in private Microsoft Team chat via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to download attachments in private chat via graph API. When I execute the below query in Microsoft Graph Explorer. I am able to get the attachment id and path.
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/chats/{chat-id}/messages/{message-id}/](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/chats/%7Bchat-id%7D/messages/%7Bmessage-id%7D/)

**But how can I download this file?**

Files are not available when requested for hostedContents. So, I believe hostedContents is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the files are hosted in chat so it will not give 404 before but after  exporting to onedrive then it will delete from there thats why its returning 404.

You have to use below API's to download file from onedrive because its exported to onedrive.

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content
GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
GET /me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/content
GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}/content
GET /shares/{shareIdOrEncodedSharingUrl}/driveItem/content
GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
GET /users/{userId}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
```

Reference Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Agree, but I am not able to find any linking.
I am traversing Microsoft teams. From there I have to jump to one drive. How should I know the file which I found in one drive belongs to this particular chat. 
Is there any linking available?

Comment: @AmitRawat- Can you please try via using this Graph API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http